# Adding new user control programmatically in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Hey so first off i would like to point out that I know that there are several other questions about this topic up here, I have even done this exact thing myself before. I am asking on here because I do not know what my problem is.

Here is the code where I attempt to display the new user control

```
private void ValidationLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EntrySuggestion t_ES = new EntrySuggestion();
        t_ES.Show();
        MainScreen home = new MainScreen();
        home.Show();
    }
```

I was trying to get the t_ES to display (which it does not) but the main Screen does. Both of these are User Controls.

Here is the code for my EntrySuggestion User control

```
 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TeamManagementSystem
{
    public partial class EntrySuggestion : UserControl
    {
        private ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

        public EntrySuggestion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public EntrySuggestion(ArrayList i)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            items = (ArrayList)i.Clone();
        }

        private void EntrySuggestion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                RadioButton t_RB = new RadioButton();
                t_RB.Text = item;
                ItemSuggestionTable.Controls.Add(t_RB);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do want to use the second constructor but I cannot get this to work with either. Any help would be great

Comment: Is MainScreen derived from a Form? You cannot simply display floating UserControl, they need to be anchored to something.

Comment: I'm trying to remember...when you add controls to a Windows form (in your case, your t_RB radio buttons), do you need to explicitly set their visibility to have them show up?

Comment: Have you checked its bounds to see if they are on screen? And has it been added to the form controls?

Comment: Main Screen is actually a Form, i do not remember doing this. What is the difference between a form and a UserControl? is there no other way to display a popup usercontrol?

Comment: @lamilambkin - Add the control to a form, and show the form.

Comment: If you want to display a popup usercontrol, you need to put it into a Window, otherwise, how do you close it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add your user control to the display surface of the main form (or another container already present)

```
    MainScreen home = new MainScreen();
    home.Show();
    EntrySuggestion t_ES = new EntrySuggestion();
    home.Controls.Add(t_ES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your user control to the form:

```
home.Controls.Add(t_ES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make entry suggestion inherit the form class or add it to an existing form using form.Controls.Add. Remember, it's a user control, not a user form, thus it cannot support itself, it needs a container and ultimately it has to have a form containing it somewhere.