# How to show/hide UserControl in a form when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#

I just want to open a Usercontrol (which contains buttons and textboxes) in a windows form when I click a button.

I created form1 with button1 and botton2 and also created Usercontrol1 and Usercontrol2 . now in form1 I want to call Usercontrol1 (open it in form1) when button1 is pressed and then press button2 to show Usercontrol2 and hide Usercontrol1 but I dont know how to do it. I created an object for Usercontrol1 in form1 (Usercontrol1.visible = true/False) but it didnt work.
please help.
Thank you

here is the code:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Usercontrol1 uc1 = new Usercontrol1 ();
        uc1.Visible = true;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Usercontrol1 uc1 = new Usercontrol1 ();
        uc1.Visible = false;

        Usercontrol2 uc2 = new Usercontrol2 ();
        uc2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code for this?

Comment: In form1 you should remove it from controls as: `this.form1.Controls.Remove(userControl1)`;

Comment: hi  Aswin Ramakrishnan. I dont have code. but only this: Usercontrol1 uc1 = new Usercontrol1();  uc1.Visible = true;   // this code inside a button click and when i clicked it nothing happens. can you help please?

Comment: @naouf you need to show your actual code.. edit your original question and paste what you have there..

Comment: do a google search on `ParentForm` which is a `property of `UserControl` and you set it's visibility doing something like this 
`((YourForms)(this.ParentForm)).ControlMainScreen.Visible = false;` lots of examples of how to do this on the internet.

Comment: I added the code. thank you

Comment: Niraj Doshi . I tried your code but form1 option didnt show up after writing "this"? any idea? thank you

Comment: First learn how to [add a UserControl correctly to a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530323/adding-new-user-control-programmatically-in-windows-forms), once you have done that then you can get the instance of the control and show/hide it.  All your current code is doing is creating instances of controls and setting the Visible property without actually adding the control to the Form

Comment: Hi  KiwiPiet. I don't want to drag the usercontrols to the form because I am planning to create 10 user controls with buttons and textboxes on them so if I drag all the 10 user controls to form1 it won't fit. so I just want to add user controls to form using code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(this.Controls.Contains(this.userControl1))
                 this.Controls.Remove(this.userControl1);
           if(!this.Controls.Contains(this.userControl2))
            this.Control.Add(this.userControl2);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!this.Controls.Contains(this.userControl1))
                 this.Control.Add(this.userControl1);
           if(this.Controls.Contains(this.userControl2))
                this.Controls.Remove(this.userControl2);
        }
```

Comment: `this` is redundant here

Comment: Ya you are right, it was just old-school style, so I left it there ! Even the winforms designer keeps them !