# Adding controls to a new class

Tags: c#, class

I have declared a class called `SubjectRow`, each instance of which has its own controls inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`:

```
public class SubjectRow : Control
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        public ComboBox subjectBox = new ComboBox();
        public Label maxBox = new Label();
        public TextBox nBox = new TextBox();
        public TextBox aBox = new TextBox();
        public TextBox mBox = new TextBox();
        public TextBox eBox = new TextBox();
        public TextBox cBox = new TextBox();

        public SubjectRow()
        {
            counter++;
            subjectBox.Location = new Point(100, 300);
        }
    }
```

In my `SubjectRow()` method, you can see my attempt to make the `ComboBox subjectBox` visible on the form using `new Point(left, top)`. However, this does nothing and the form is still blank on runtime.

I am pretty new to C#, but my understanding is that the `SubjectRow()` method is run whenever a new instance of `class SubjectRow` is created. So why does this not work? How can I have the `subjectBox` control appear on the form at a given location?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am also not permitted to use the designer on Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you add the code that creates the instance?

Comment: this is not how you create custom controls look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530323/adding-new-user-control-programmatically-in-windows-forms

Comment: Inherit from UserControl and add all your controls to collection Controls

Comment: Keeping your text boxes/combo boxes/etc. as variables doesn't automatically add them to your parent. Inherit a container control instead, such as a Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told that you had a form, so you should add `form` parameter to constructor;

```
public SubjectRow (Form f)
{
    counter++;
    subjectBox.Location = new Point(100, 300);
    f.Controls.Add(subjectBox);
}
```

And in the form's code behind, create an instance like this.

```
SubjectRow test= new SubjectRow (this);
```

Hope helps,

Comment: The quickest and easiest answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Control does not implement UserControl

Below is the correct way of doing it

**MyUserControl.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ControlTest
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.txtName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // txtName
            // 
            this.txtName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(107, 18);
            this.txtName.Name = "txtName";
            this.txtName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(305, 20);
            this.txtName.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lblName
            // 
            this.lblName.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 23);
            this.lblName.Name = "lblName";
            this.lblName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.lblName.TabIndex = 1;
            this.lblName.Text = "Name";
            // 
            // MyUserControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblName);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtName);
            this.Name = "MyUserControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(433, 57);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblName;
    }
}
```

**In your Form, add the user control:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ControlTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MyUserControl myUserControl1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myUserControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.myUserControl1.Name = "myUserControl1";
            this.myUserControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(433, 57);
            this.myUserControl1.TabIndex = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample quick and dirty:

```
public partial class SubjectRow : UserControl
  {
    private ComboBox comboBox1;
    private Label label1;
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private TextBox textBox2;
    private TextBox textBox3;
    private TextBox textBox4;
    private TextBox textBox5;

    public SubjectRow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
      label1 = new Label();
      textBox1 = new TextBox();
      textBox2 = new TextBox();
      textBox3 = new TextBox();
      textBox4 = new TextBox();
      textBox5 = new TextBox();

      Controls.Add(textBox5);
      Controls.Add(textBox4);
      Controls.Add(textBox3);
      Controls.Add(textBox2);
      Controls.Add(textBox1);
      Controls.Add(label1);
      Controls.Add(comboBox1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public SubjectRow (Form f, int pointX=100, int pointY=300)
{
    counter++;
    subjectBox.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
    f.Controls.Add(subjectBox);
}

SubjectRow test= new SubjectRow (this,100,300); // You can control position of every control
```